# Sorted Two-Way Tabulation of Many Values

Tags: sorting, stata, frequency, word-frequency

I have a decent-sized dataset (about 18,000 rows). I have two variables that I want to tabulate, one taking on many string values, and the second taking on just 4 values. I want to tabulate the string values by the 4 categories. I need these sorted. I have tried several commands, including `tabsort`, which works, but only if I restrict the number of rows it uses to the first 603 (at least with the way it is currently sorted). If the number of rows is greater than this, then I get the `r(134)` error that there are too many values. Is there anything to be done? My goal is to create a table with the most common words and export it to LaTeX. Would it be a lot easier to try and do this in something like R?

Comment: How do you want them sorted?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear. I want them sorted by frequency, so the most-commonly occurring words would appear at the top. I am not picky on what this exactly means. My preferred sorting would be the same sorting that one would obtain without taking splitting them up by the 4 values (i.e., that which would obtain using a one-way tabulate). But it would also be fine if it were sorted by frequency by just one of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, via `contract` and `texsave` from SSC:

```
/* Fake Data */
set more off
clear
set matsize 5000
set seed 12345
set obs 1000
gen x = string(rnormal())
expand mod(_n,10)
gen y = mod(_n,4)

/* Collapse Data to Get Frequencies for Each x-y Cell */
preserve    
    contract x y, freq(N)
    reshape wide N, i(x) j(y)
    forvalues v=0/3 {
        lab var N`v' "`v'" // need this for labeling
        replace N`v'=0 if missing(N`v')
    }
    egen T = rowtotal(N*)
    gsort -T x // sort by occurrence
    keep if T > 0 // set occurrence threshold
    capture ssc install texsave
    texsave x N0 N1 N2 N3 using "tab_x_y.tex", varlabel replace title("tab x y")
restore

/* Check Calculations */
type "tab_x_y.tex"
tab x y, rowsort
```

Comment: Following the `keep if T > 0` you could alternatively just `list  x N? 
`

Comment: @NickCox I think the OP wanted a LaTeX table, so printing the output to the screen would not be sufficient.

Comment: Sure, but others interested in this thread need not be so limited.

Comment: @NickCox To that end, I think `tab x y, rowsort` would be better.

Comment: Yes and no.  If `tabulate` works, then fine. But the OP has already reported being bitten by the limits on `tabsort` (not explained, but from SSC). As its author I know that `tabsort` is just a wrapper for `tabulate`; so, `tabulate` can work no better here than `tabsort`. That's why I am recommending `list`.